# Google Analytics won't track events

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the Measurement Protocol for event tracking.

It correctly displays pageview hits, however fails to detect event hits.

Pageview that succeeds:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
                               v=1
                               &tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1
                               &cid=555
                               &uip=10.10.10.10
                               &t=pageview
                               &dl=mysite.com
```

Event that fails:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?
                               v=1
                               &tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1
                               &cid=555
                               &uip=10.10.10.10
                               &t=event
                               &ec=category
                               &ea=view
```

All of the required parameters are included - v, tid, cid, t, ec, ea. How can I make the event work?

Looks like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing EL

- ec – Event Category
- ea – Event Action
- el – Event Label
- ev – Event Value

> &t=event&ec=list&ea=accounts&el=userclicked&ev=10

When it works it should show up in the Real-time makes testing easer :)

**Update:**

I just tested with the following and it works:

http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-1&cid=555&uip=10.10.10.10&t=event&t=event&ec=list&ea=accounts&el=userclicked&ev=10

Note: Remember it takes between 24 - 72 hours for a new Google Analytics account to log data I don't think this is the issue since you said that pageviews are working.   It also takes 24 hours for data to show up in the standard reports so you will have to check the real-time reports to see that its working.

Comment: el and ev are optional... I've tried with and without them with no success.

Comment: there are a number of fields in the measurement protocol that are required but don't state that they are required.  its a known issue.   page views are working correct?

Comment: Updated the answer this time I actually tested a request.

Comment: Hell, it's working! Turns out I was looking at the wrong tab. Sorry about the trouble.